# Como ter acesso ao IHostingEnvironment fora do Controller no ASP.NET Core?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

Estou atualizando uma API do ASP.NET Framework para ASP.NET Core e estou preso em um problema.

No .NET Framework utilizava o seguinte:

```
public GmailConnection(){
    serverCredentialPath = HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~/Credentials/Google/Gmail/"); //Variavel da classe sendo atribuida pelo mapeamento
    serverClientSecret = HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~/APIS/Google/Gmail/client_secret.json"); //Variavel da classe sendo atribuida pelo mapeamento
}
```

Porém no ASP.NET Core só consigo ter acesso ao `IHostingEnvironment` através do Controller:

```
private IHostingEnvironment _env;
public MarketingController(IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    _env = env;
    string path = env.WebRootPath;
}
```

Como faço para ter acesso ao `IHostingEnvironment` através de outra classe que não seja Controller?

Comment: não seria o caso de atribuir esse valor há uma classe abstrata e propriedades estáticas?

Comment: Sim, mas como receber o `IHostingEnvironment ` nessa classe estatica?

Comment: Já tentei de diversas formas...

Comment: Em que lugar essa classe vai estar? Não me ficou claro onde quer usar o `IHostingEnvironment `. Uma opção talvez seja injetar via construtor.

Comment: Barbetta, então, na versão antiga do meu programa, ficava dentro do construtor de uma classe chamada `GmailConnection`, olha a edição. Preciso receber esses valores dentro do construtor ou através de uma classe estática, o problema é que não consigo injeta-la via construtor...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Você cria uma variável do tipo `IHostingEnvironment` na classe `Startup.cs`.
2. Depois atribui o valor recebido no construtor da classe.

   ```
   private readonly IHostingEnvironment enviroment;

   public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env)
   {
       enviroment = env;

       // ...

   }
   ```
3. No método `ConfigureServices` você registra um serviço (usei `Singleton`) passando a referência de `IHostingEnvironment` que foi recebida no construtor da classe.

   public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
       {

   ```
       services.AddMvc();

       services.AddSingleton(enviroment);
   }
   ```
4. No construtor da `Controller` você continua recebendo por injeção de dependência a instância de `IHostingEnviroment`.

   ```
       public HomeController(IHostingEnvironment env)
   {
       var gmailConnection = new GmailConnection(env);
   }
   ```
5. Na classe (no caso eu criei a classe em um em projeto `ClassLibrary`) você continua recebendo a instância de `IHostingEnviroment` pelo construtor.

   using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;

   ```
   namespace Infraestrutura
   {
       public class GmailConnection
       {
           private readonly string serverCredentialPath;
           private readonly string serverClientSecret;            
           private readonly IHostingEnvironment env;

       public GmailConnection(IHostingEnvironment env)
       {          
           this.env = env;
           string path = env.WebRootPath;             
       }
   }
   ```

[Referência](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40946685/how-to-use-ihostingenvironment)
[Injeção de dependência na classe Statup.cs](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/aspnet/core/fundamentals/startup?view=aspnetcore-2.2)